# Optimality of the Bayes classifier

Tags: classification, bayesian, continuous-data, proof

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathcal{X}$ and $Y$ a random variable with values in $\{0,1\}$. Is it true that : 
$$\mathbb{P}(g(X) \ne Y) = \int_\mathcal{X} \mathbb{P}\big(g(X)\ne Y \hspace{1mm} \mid X=x\big)d\mathbb{P}_X(x)$$
?

I agree with this equality in the case where $X$ is discrete (i.e $\mathcal{X}$ is a countable set), but I can't prove why it holds in the general setting where $X$ is not discrete and does not have a density function. Actually, I can't prove the equality when $X$ has a density neither.

I came across this equality in at least 2 articles about statistical learning theory :

- [first article](http://84.89.132.1/~lugosi/lecturenotes.ps), page 4, proof of theorem 1.1
- [second article](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rmcastro/2DI70/files/2DI70_Lecture_Notes.pdf), page 16, proof of proposition 1

The statements, whose proof uses the equality above, say that the Bayes classifier realizes the minimum of the risk $\mathbb{P}(g(X)\ne Y)$ over all measurable functions $g$.

Comment: This equality looks exactly like the continuous version of the law of total probability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to treat separately the cases where $X$ is discrete, continuous or neither.  We are just taking an iterated expectation here, which is always permissible.  The idea is that since probabilities are simply expectations of indicator random variables we can always write something like

\begin{align}
P(g(X) \neq Y) &= \text{E} \left (I_{ \{ g(X) \neq Y \}} \right ) \\
&= \text{E} \left [ \text{E} \left (I_{ \{ g(X) \neq Y \}} \mid X  \right ) \right ] \\
&= \text{E}[ P(g(X) \neq Y \mid X)]
\end{align}

and the integral above is just another way of writing this down.  Again, this holds true no matter what "type" of random variable $X$ happens to be.

Comment: You are using $1_{\{g(X)\ne Y\} }= E ( 1_{\{g(X)\ne Y\}} / X)$. Is it because you consider that $1_{\{g(X)\ne Y\}}$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable ?

Comment: OK I got it. You didn't use the equality $1_{\{g(X)\ne Y\}} = E(1_{\{g(X)\ne Y\}}/X)$. You actually used $E(1_{\{g(X)\ne Y\}})=E [ E(1_{\{g(X)\ne Y\}} / X)]$, which is true for any sigma-algebra. This is what you called iterated expectation.

Comment: I still have a question though. I know what is the probability of an event knowing another event, but I've never seen the probability of an event knowing a random variable. So I don't see what $P(g(X) \ne Y | X )$ means ???

Comment: $P(g(X) \neq Y)$ is just a number, but $P(g(X) \neq Y \mid X)$ is a *random function* of $X$.  For a more concrete example, imagine you roll a die, call the outcome $X$ and then flip a coin with probability of heads $1 / X$.  $P(\text{heads})$ is some fixed number, but $P(\text{heads} \mid X) = 1 / X$.

Comment: Ok for the intuitive example. But is there a formal definition of the probability  knowing a random variable, like that of the conditional expectation ?

Comment: It's exactly the same as the definition for conditional expectation given a random variable, again using the fact that $P(A) = \text{E}(I_A)$.

Comment: Do you mean that you denote $E[I_A|\mathcal{F}]$ (which is well defined) by $P(A|\mathcal{F})$ for any sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ ?