# Bayes decision boundary naming

Tags: classification, bayesian, optimal

Why the optimal classifier is called "Bayes". I do not see the connection with being Bayesian or so.

Edit: This question asks about naming. Not about math.

---

Another phrasing of the question:  Given that the Bayesian classifier is optimal (under certain constraints) does not explain why that particular classifier is called "Bayesian."  Why do we call such a classifier "Bayesian" rather than some other name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Bayes Classifier the ideal classifier?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191924/why-is-bayes-classifier-the-ideal-classifier) or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237698/bayes-classifier or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236829/optimality-of-the-bayes-classifier

Comment: My question asks about naming, i.e why it is named Bayes. I understand why such a classifier is ideal.

Comment: It is not a duplicate actually.

Comment: Indeed.... this is not a duplicate question.  Showing that the Bayesian classifier is optimal (under certain restrictions) does not explain *why* such a classifier is called "Bayesian."  In principle, such a classifier could be called anything.